# Prime ideal in Dedekind domain

Tags: dedekind-domain

Let $\mathcal{o}$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions, $L$ a finite separable field extension of $K$, and $\mathcal{O}$ the integral closure of $\mathcal{o}$ in $L$. When $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in the Dedekind domain $\mathcal{o}$, then one can consider the ideal $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}$ in the Dedekind domain $\mathcal{O}$, and this is sometimes abbreviated as simply $\mathfrak{p}$. What is the relation between $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}$? Are they in 1-1 correspondence? The latter is usually not a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}$, right?

Comment: You are right, the latter is often not a prime ideal. Prime ideals often split in extensions, sometimes they ramify, sometimes they remain prime. You might wish to google "Ramification theory" or some variant thereof to read about such phenomena.

Comment: Richt, google for "ramification" in algebraic number theory.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

Comment: I guess $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}\cap\mathcal{o}=\mathfrak{p}$ so $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}$ are in 1-1 correspondence. Right?